# Is it better to add/remove vtkActors or toogle their visibility?

Tags: user-interface, vtk

I'm writing a GUI to display a `vtkUnstructuredGrid` containing several scalars and vectors. The objective is to let the user decide whether s/he wants to display a color map, or a vector field of glyphs or just the mesh itself.

That gives me basically four actors: one for the map, one for the glyphs, one for the mesh and a last one for the colorbar. Depending on the user's choice, I need to display either the mesh alone, or the map and the colorbar, or the glyphs and the colorbar. I can prepare each actor independently and store them as an attribute of my GUI for a later access.

I'm wondering what is the most efficient approach for rendering only what the user wants:

- toggling the visibility of each actor depending on the use case (using a `.SetVisibility(True/False)`), or
- adding/removing the corresponding actors to/from the `vtkRenderer`.

Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

--- Edit ---

A corollary is : when a `vtkRenderer` renders actors, does it skip the invisible ones or does it renders them, then hides them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you noticed a performance difference or something? I would have said those two techniques should do exactly the same thing at runtime.

Comment: Actually, I didn't try to measure performances. On a practical point of view, as I keep a list of the actors in my widget, it is easier to toggle their visibility, as I keep them in a list. Deleting an actor directly from the renderer would require to find it first (which entry in the corresponding `vtkActorCollection`)...

Comment: If there is no performance difference, then do whatever is easier :)